# facts with enumeration

Tags: c, enums, int, constants, gnu

I have found in one pdf articles that not handling an enumeration constant will generate warnings. but in my Bloodshed/DevC++ compiler it works fine without any warnings. where is the problem?
here is a snippet,

```
enum fruit {banana, apple, blueberry, mango} my_fruit;
```

according to that pdf document handling banana, apple and blueberry but not mango will generate a warning, but i cant find the warning.

another thing is what is the purpose of enum variable my_fruit here. what i am wondering about is there any special uses of enum variable in C. If there is no distinctive use rather normal int then why they are present?

Comment: What to you mean by **handling** ? Can you link the pdf resource you refer to ?

Comment: handling means here just using later. think of using first three in a switch block but not the last one...

Comment: ok then mention the `switch` in your question.

Answer (score 4):

The warning is referring to the use of an `enum fruit` variable in a `switch`:

```
switch (my_fruit)
{
case banana:
    break;
case apple:
    break;
case blueberry:
    break;
}
```

When compiled with `gcc -Wall` the compiler emits the following warning:

> enumeration value 'mango' not handled in switch

This is a useful diagnostic as it alerts the developer to a potential oversight. This is not possible with a collection of unrelated (from the compiler's perspective) `const int` variables.